# Changing font color of <a> contained within <li>, but on hover over <li>

Tags: css

I have a `<li>` that contains an `<a href>`

```
<li><a href="http://site.com">Page</a></li>
```

I'd like to change the background color and text color of each `<li>` item as it's hovered over. I found that the background color is best changed by targetting the `li:hover` and not the `a:hover` because the `a:hover` changes the background of only a small portion of the line (the part that has the `<a>` text).

```
li:hover { background-color:green; }
```

What I'd also like to do is change the font color (that's the `<a>`). When I do it the first way below, it has no effect on the `<a>` text color. And when I do it the second way below, I'd have to hover specifically on the `<a>` for the font color to change, not just anywhere in the `<li>` bullet line.

```
li:hover { background-color:green; color:red; } //first way
a:hover { color:red; } //second way
```

**Is there a way with css to change the font color of the contained `<a href>` when the `<li>` is hovered over? again, this is what the html markup looks like:**

```
<li><a href="http://site.com">Page</a></li>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way that works on IE6 is to still target the link, but make the link fill the whole of the space inside the `<li>`:

```
li a { display: block; }
li a:hover { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 49):

```
li:hover a { color: red }
```

[:hover](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) documentation.

[IE5/6 only support :hover on links](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), so make sure you're not testing on those browsers.