# Wil css hover property implement on all other anchor tag automatically?

Tags: css

I worried about my coded css. Actually i had to change the color of anchor tag on hover of `li`. So i searched about this and find an answer. This accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988122/changing-font-color-of-a-contained-within-li-but-on-hover-over-li) is working fine. But i'm worried about this line css.

```
.slider-menu ul li:hover a{ color:#ffffff; }
```

Because as per my understand there is no parent class of `a`, so that's why i just want to clear my concept that above code will change the every anchor tag color on same page or it will just change the child anchor tag of `.slider-menu ul li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will only affect anchors (`<a>`) whose parent is a hovered `<li>` whose parent is an `<ul>` that is a child of `.slider-menu`, specifically.

Comment: You means it will not affect on other except child `ul` of `.slider-menu`.. Thanks

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It will affect only `<a>`tag of all `li` whose parent is `.slider-menu`.
Other than that it won't.