# Color in link tag doesn't work but color in div in link tag works?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why doesn't this work (in terms of text color):

```
.navbarDivText {
    color: #DAA520;
}
.navbarDiv {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


<li class="navbarDiv" >
   <a href="index.php" class = "navbarDivText">Main Page</a>
</li>
```

But this does:

```
<li class="navbarDiv" >
   <a href="index.php">
     <div class = "navbarDivText">Main Page</div>
   </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/ep8dcqe4/

Comment: Probably you have a color asigned to your links `<a>` tag that is overwritten your first example. Just inspect it with chrome to check

Comment: your code works perfectly.. i don't see any problem

Comment: Show us your full html and css.

Comment: What do you want the color should be of text here?

Comment: The text is red in both cases for me, but the underline of the link is in another color, red in the first case and blue (default) in the second case. Is this your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this there are two cases if you give the color for list it will change the color of list and the anchor remained blue by default with underline.

If you also want to to change the color of anchor in a list you should have also give the styling for anchor means text-decoration and color whatever style you want.

See example here hope this will help you. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988122/changing-font-color-of-a-contained-within-li-but-on-hover-over-li)

More demo: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine to me, clear cookies and try.

```css
.navbarDivText {
  color: #DAA520;
}

.navbarDiv {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="navbarDiv"><a href="index.php" class="navbarDivText">Main Page</a></li>
```

Could do this as well,

```
.navbarDiv a, a:visited {
  color: #DAA520;
}
```

or

```
.navbarDivText:link, .navbarDivText:visited {
  color: #DAA520;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is probably overriding this...

You'll need to be more specific e.g.

```
a.navbarDivText {
  color: #DAA520;
}
```

You may have to use:

```
a.navbarDivText {
  color: #DAA520!important;
}
```

If for some reason that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

On a side note you should only put a div inside an `a` tag if you are using the HTML5 doctype, which I imagine you are.

When a link is clicked the browser will give it a color to show it has been visited. So you could try the below `:visited` selector. If that doesn't work then it is likely that another style is overriding your style. As mentioned in the comments, inspect the element in the developer console and see if your style is being overridden.

```
.navbarDivText:link, .navbarDivText:visited
{
   color: #DAA520;
}
```